# How to get last column name from mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

I want to retrieve the last column name from a mysql table.
For example the schema would look like this:

`TABLE example {surname,firstname,birthdate}`

In this example I want to get the column name "birthdate" from table "example".
How do I achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html

Comment: Why on Earth does it matter, which column is the first or last in a table? It is not really a good practice to rely on the position of fields within a table to retrieve certain data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT 
COLUMN_NAME,
ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
AND TABLE_NAME ='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

[**Information_schema.columns**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) stores column specific information.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one, The Solution from command line mysql
[Learn about Information Schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)

```
mysql>USE information_schema;
mysql>SELECT COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<--DATABASE_NAME-->' AND   TABLE_NAME='<--TABLENAME-->' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION desc limit 1
```